# What is Sublime Text Folder in Volumes?

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

There is a "Sublime Text" folder in my "/Volumes" directory. Why is it there and not in Applications? I do not know how Mac's applications work. I am new to Mac.

Comment: How did you install Sublime Text on your Mac?

Comment: By .dmg file from https://sublimetext.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install your application to any folder you want. I found a nice [description](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64845/how-do-i-install-applications-from-a-dmg-file) to install an application on a macos. If you do the installation you only copy the application from the dmg file to the applications folder. Maybe you can remove your installed sublime text by moving the application to the trash and reinstall it.

At the end I would recommend you to use [Homebrew/Cask](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask) to install your applications. I think that makes it easier if you do not want to use the graphical user interface.